# How i can make kaaproject as gateway for arduino

Tags: c++, iot, arduino-uno, kaa

Hi guys I am using Kaaserver for our IoT project and now i faced with one problem 
I would like to ask you how i can send data with arduino to Kaaserver I read some where is possible to configure kaa as gateway and i wanna to know how ?

Comment: What do you mean by configuring Kaa Server as a gateway? If you want to send some data received from a sensor like a temperature to the server, you can  use [Kaa log appenders](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Collecting+data+from+endpoints).

Comment: actually i would like to send data from arduino to kaa , now i wrote kaa log appender in raspberry pi and i would like to get data from arduino then send to the kaa with kaa gateway. becuase before i read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kaaproject/BbbZefAHOas and then i did not understand what is meaning about kaa gateway ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other board as gateway for Arduino, so you'll need some device supported by Kaa (ESP8266, BeagleBone, Raspberry PI, etc.).

You can generate Kaa SDK for your device and write an application which will collect data from Arduino by serial port and send it to Kaa server using SDK.

Comment: Do you know how to write Kaa sdk into ESP8266?